# Image upload after client resize: cloudinary

Tags: php, image-uploading, image-resizing, cloudinary

I'm able to resize images (client side) using [this](https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel) neat library.
I'm also able to upload images directly from the browser to Cloudinary, using this code:

```
<?php echo cl_image_upload_tag('image_id', array("callback" => $cors_location)); ?>
```

This basically creates an input field (type=file), and when you click on "browse" and you select a file, the uploading automatically starts.

My question: how to make these two things work together? I would need to use the cropped image to upload to Cloudinary, but I have no idea where to start... I've tried mimicking the "browse" thing with jQuery, but that didn't work out...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Cloudinary supports uploading from DATA URLs (Base 64). For more information:
http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/25785301-How-to-upload-Base64-data-to-Cloudinary-using-Post-Request